# How to fix prettytable installation

Tags: python, installation, pip, mbed, prettytable

I can install, uninstall and upgrade **prettytable** using `pip [un]install [-U] prettytable`.  But running the `mbed-tools compile` command keeps on reporting "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prettytable'`"

I can see the package is added to my `...\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Lib\site-packages\` folder.  According to my environmental path the folder `...\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Scripts\` is added and many packages has en `.exe` file installed there, but `prettytabe` is missing.  Could this be the problem?  If so, how do I install it and ensure that it actually has en exe install too?

I'm running python 3.9.7 on pretty-much-the-latest Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried using `pip3` rather than `pip` ? It is strongly recommended for Python 3+ versions.

Comment: Yes - I have indeed.  No difference.  Could it perhaps be that I'm running Python 2.7 as well?  Different versions of Python should be able to run together.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out I had Python 3.8.7 installed together with Python 3.9.7.  So uninstalling the older one solved the problem...